# Making Custom URLs with Django for Template Menue

Tags: python, django, django-templates

The idea is to take my views address which in my case is `hikes.views.displayHike` and pass it different id numbers from my database so that there will be a list of links generated by a for loop in the template.  If I do this:

```
{%block content%}   
    {% for x in data %}
        <a href="{%url hikes.views.displayHike x.hikeId:{{x.hikeId}}%}"> {{x.name}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{%endblock%}
```

or

```
{%block content%}   
    {% for x in data %}
        <a href="{%url 'hikes.views.displayHike' {{x.hikeId}}%}"> {{x.name}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{%endblock%}
```

The view for both of the above is simple:

```
def hikeHome(request):
    data = Hikes.objects.all()       
    return render(request, 'hikeHome.html', {'data':data})
```

I get a syntax error :

```
Django Version: 1.7
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: ':{{x.hikeId}}' from 'x.hikeId:{{x.hikeId}}'
```

However if I hardcode in a value like this:

```
{%block content%}   
    {% for x in data %}
        <a href="{%url 'hikes.views.displayHike' 1 %}"> {{x.name}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{%endblock%}
```

It works great but I dont want to have a hard coded value... I want to be able to just put this in the for loop let it run and display all the possible links for the user.

I also attempted to make the URL in the view, put it into a dictionary and access the name as the key and the value as the URL like so:

view:

```
def hikeHome(request):
    hikes = Hikes.objects.all()    
    data = dict()
    for x in hikes:
        data[x.name] = reverse(displayHike,args=[1])

    return render(request, 'hikeHome.html', {'data':data})
```

template:

```
{%block content%}   
    {% for x, y in data.items %}
        <a href="{%url {{y}}%}"> {{x}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{%endblock%}`
```

This gets the error message:

```
Django Version: 1.7
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '{{y}}' from '{{y}}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/

```
{% block content %}
    {% for x in data %}
        <a href="{%url 'hikes.views.displayHike' x.hikeId %}"> {{x.name}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, don't forget to include your url as a string in Django 1.5+ and not use the `{{ }}` for URL args.